# AngularJS: Error in my global function of $rootscope not defined, $scope not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually,I'm new in angularJS, My scenario is:

```
$rootScope.synchronization = function($scope, $rootScope, $window, $http) 
{
    if(localStorage.getItem('job_id') != "" && localStorage.getItem('job_id') > 0)
    {
        alert("found job id!"); 
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('job_id'));    
        if(localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks') != "" && localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks') > 0)
        {
            alert("found done tasks ids!");
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks'));

            $scope.done_tasks = {};
            $scope.done_tasks = localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks');
            $scope.job_id = localStorage.getItem('job_id');
            console.log($scope.done_tasks);             
            var userData = $http(
            {
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost/t-app/mobile-data/update-tasks.php",
                data: {
                        done_tasks : $scope.done_tasks,
                        job_id: $scope.job_id,
                    },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            });
            userData.success(function (userdataobject)
            {
                $rootScope.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];
                $rootScope.message = userdataobject["message"];

                localStorage.setItem('job_id', '');
                localStorage.setItem('job_id.done_tasks', '');

            })  
        }

        console.log(localStorage.getItem('job_id'));
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('job_id'));
    }

};
```

and in my controller im using this:

```
$interval( $rootScope.synchronization, 2000 , 1);
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

and

```
app.js (line 48)
Error: $http is not a function
$rootScope.synchronization@http://localhost/task-app/js/app.js:52:20
```

Please help me out to sort this problem out... I have added the $scope, $rootScope, $window, $http but still not worked for me. Have a look on my scenario please.

Comment: where you define the first bit? adding your controllers/app definition would be good

Comment: why are you even trying to use `$rootScope` for this logic in the first place? this is the job for a service, not for `$rootScope`.

Comment: plus, I'm not sure that wrapping `$http` inside a function that is called by `$interval` makes a lot of sense.  `$http` is async, so you aren't accomplishing anything by repeatedly calling it except generating tons of callbacks.

Comment: + as far as I know dependency injection does not work in `$interval` callback

Comment: Can you help me our to make better logic ? @Claies . thank you in advance..

Comment: @Claies i want to use this function into all of my controllers this is why i define this on app level..

Answer (score 1):

You can define this synchronization function in your controller, I dont think you need to use rootscope at all. You can use this controller;

```
yourApp.controller("yourController", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', 'localStorage',
    function ($scope, $http, $timeout, localStorage) {

        var synchronization = function () {
            if (localStorage.getItem('job_id') != "" && localStorage.getItem('job_id') > 0) {

                if (localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks') != "" && localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks') > 0) {
                    $scope.done_tasks = {};
                    $scope.done_tasks = localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks');
                    $scope.job_id = localStorage.getItem('job_id');

                    var userData = $http({
                        method: "post",
                        url: "http://localhost/t-app/mobile-data/update-tasks.php",
                        data: {
                            done_tasks: $scope.done_tasks,
                            job_id: $scope.job_id
                        },
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    });
                    userData.success(function (userdataobject) {
                        //* I added response to $scope *//
                        $scope.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];
                        $scope.message = userdataobject["message"];

                        localStorage.setItem('job_id', '');
                        localStorage.setItem('job_id.done_tasks', '');

                        $timeout(synchronization, 2000);
                    });
                }
            }
        };

    }]);
```

Just copied your function to controller and arrenged injections..

Note: I used timeout service to recall this function every 2 sec instead of interval, you can tweak that according to your need, carrying the line out of synchronization function will call it once after 2 sec.

Comment: Actually i want to call this function into many of controllers... :(

Comment: If that is the case you should use a **factory provider**. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe

Comment: Sir, I'm getting this error now `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest` can you please help me to turn my this `$rootscope.synchronization()` function into service or factory provider in my this fiddle [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ9NvTo0TE6MBo4oRRSj?p=preview).. :(

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the correct values into the function as I can see from your call:

`$interval( $rootScope.synchronization, 2000 , 1);`

Interval calls your function, and the synchronization function requires  four parameters:

`$rootScope.synchronization = function($scope, $rootScope, $window, $http){/**/}`

You can pass the parameters like this:

`$interval( $rootScope.synchronization, 2000 , 1, false, $scope, $rootScope, $window, $http);`

Note the false in the above call to `$interval`. This will ensure that you're out of the `$apply` cycle which solves the `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`.
Docs for `$interval` are [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Also I would suggest changing this code to `$timeout` as you're doing it only once. Besides, that you should use `$window.localStorage` instead of `localStorage`.

Edit 2:
Based on OP's comment a service would be the best solution:

```
myApp.factory('SynchronizationService', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
    '$window', '$location', '$interval', '$http',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, $location, $interval, $http) {
        return {
            synchronization: function () { /*your code here*/}
        };
    }]);
```

Then you can call this from a controller by injecting the service, and calling the exposed method:

```
controller('mainCtrl', ['SynchronizationService', function(SyncService) {
    SyncService.synchronization();
});
```

Comment: Please checkout error of `
Error: $http is not a function
$rootScope.synchronization@http://localhost/task-app/js/app.js:52:20` is still here..

Comment: please see the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ9NvTo0TE6MBo4oRRSj?p=preview) too..

Comment: Please copy how you're calling the `$interval/$timeout`, and the controller function definition. Seems like you're missing an injection for `$http`

Comment: I replaced the alerts with console.log, and added an error handler for the `$http` call. The [edited plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vEeT3gP0LhLQSDhgUO3) works and correctly fails on fetching request, as the domain is non-existant.

Comment: thanks for your this suport. It works in plunker.. but I don't know in here in my app.. it is not working. now I have copied this `rootScope` function to my any of contreller.. and it is working fine... I dont know whats the issue. but it sucked me more then 4 hours..

Comment: You should definitely make a service and inject the service into your controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the function ($interval) call
This is my suggestion:

```
$interval($rootScope.synchronization, 2000 , 1, false, $scope, $rootScope, $window, $http);
```

[$inverval API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Better solution for your problem:

```
$timeout($rootScope.synchronization, 2000, false, $scope, $rootScope, $window, $http);
```

[$timeout API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: Cool. THanks for your anser. Please also look on this code too..

`alert(localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks'));
   if(localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks') != "" && localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks') > 0)
   {
alert(localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks'));
}`
here in this i m not getting into the if condition.. and my `localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks')` is like `10,13,12` etc

Comment: thanks alot for your answer. 
Sir, I'm getting this error now `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest` can you please help me to turn my this `$rootscope.synchronization()` function into service or factory provider in my this fiddle [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ9NvTo0TE6MBo4oRRSj?p=preview).. :(