# AngularJS: unable to save the localStorage item into scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `window.localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks')` to store the values into `$scope` level variable. I'm failing to do so. Please check my code.

```
$scope.done_tasks = {};
$scope.done_tasks = window.localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks');
```

when i `alert('$scope.done_tasks');` it says `undefined` but when i use this `alert(window.localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks'));` it shows `16,17` . Why i am unable to store the values of `window.localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks')` to `$scope.done_tasks`. Help me out regarding this.

Comment: shouldn't it `alert($scope.done_tasks);` ?

Comment: same error with `alert($scope.done_tasks);` too

Comment: can you provide the setting part of localStorage ?>

Comment: I'ave clear the cache. and now it is working fine.. but another problem ariving now.. :( see my this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543506/angularjs-error-in-my-global-function-of-rootscope-not-defined-scope-not-def) 
I'm getting this error `Error: $http is not a function
$rootScope.synchronization@http://localhost/task-app/js/app.js:54:19` Please see the full code in linked question..

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi check my uper comment Sir.

Comment: please check my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpOlX6L9LOIeRRZMHhvO?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code, local storage returns string as an output , you need to parse it to object.

```
$scope.done_tasks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('job_id.done_tasks'));
```

For your ref:

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key,value);
window.localStorage.getItem(key);
```

That's how local storage works, whatever key you have provided to save value, the same key you have to use to fetch data.

Comment: please checkout this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpOlX6L9LOIeRRZMHhvO?p=preview) getting error. :(

Comment: My friend @Nirvana thanks for your editing in this plnkr.. But the error is here that 
`Error: $http is not a function
$rootScope.synchronization@http://localhost/task-app/js/app.js:53:20`

please see what error is this?

Comment: http method returns a promise and u haven't handled it properly ..pls check my commented code in controller ..

Comment: Thanks alot @Nirvana for your answer. 
Sir, I'm getting this error now `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest` can you please help me to turn my this `$rootscope.synchronization()` function into service or factory provider in this [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ9NvTo0TE6MBo4oRRSj?p=preview).. :(